# Angular 5 CanActivate only if user Object returned

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an AuthService providing a `loggedIn()` function, which should return true if logged in and false if not. However, I'm using JWT in order to keep a user logged in. Since I do not only want to check wheter a JWT is expired, but also want to check whether this Token fits to a user, I verify (if a token is stored in the local Storage) this one. How do I return a simple true or false? I tried something like this:

AuthService:

```
loggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    const token = this.loadToken();
    if (token) {
        const headers = this.server.createAuthHeaders(null, null, token);
        const httpOptions = {
            headers
        };
        return this.http.get(url, httpOptions)
        .map(user => typeof(user) === 'object')
        .catch(err => Observable.of(false));
    }
    return Observable.of(false);
}
```

and AuthGuard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.authService.loggedIn().map((loggedIn) => {
        if (!loggedIn) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }).take(1);
}
```

Comment: A CanActivate guard may return an Observable<boolean>. That's what you should return. Not a boolean, since you need an asynchronous http call, which returns... an Observable.

Comment: How would I do this? I updated the Question with the AuthGuard

Comment: You could look into Observable.of() which is an easy method of doing it. Edit: I just noticed the code of your loggedIn method, that is never going to work as the value of bool will always be false. You wrote the code with a synchronous approach, but http.get is asynchronous.

Comment: Thank you! Could you maybe give a code example of how you would implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loggedIn` is supposed to return an `Observable<boolean>`.

Simply change its code to

```
  loggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    const token = this.loadToken();
    if (token) {
      return this.http.get(url, httpOptions)
        .map(user => isObject(user))
        .catch(err => Observable.of(false));
    }
    return Observable.of(false);
  }
```

Comment: I get two errors: _Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<boolean>'_ and _Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'_. Do I have to change anything at the AuthGuard?

Comment: map is an RxJS operator. As any other operator, it must be imported. Just as you're probably already doing in AuthGuard: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`. of is a static creation method, that must be imported too: `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';`.

Comment: Still getting Errors :( _ERROR in src/app/services/auth.service.ts(65,7): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<boolean | {}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'
  Type 'boolean | {}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
src/app/services/auth.service.ts(67,34): error TS2339: Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
src/app/services/auth.service.ts(69,23): error TS2339: Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'._ . Do I have to use map or can I use subscribe as well?

Comment: The first error probably means that isObject doesn't return a boolean as it should. The scond one has already been answered in my previous comment.

Comment: I just updated my Question. There are no more errors while compiling. Thank you very much!